# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

Tags: java, db2, websphere

i am trying to automate DB testing using selenium, for that i need to connect IBM DB2. since i am facing issue in my POM file, i have manually imported the db2jcc4.jar (first i downloaded the v11.5.4_jdbc_sqlj.tar.gz from IBM site, then extracted it to get the db2jcc4.jar) in my project. while i am running the build clean install, i am getting the above class not found error. i am not sure what i am missing. it will be a great help if i get the solution.

this is the failure line: Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWzId.png)

Comment: If you are using Maven, avoid downloading the JDBC driver manually. Use the official artifacts at https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.ibm.db2/jcc. This way maven will automatically download it, put it in the classpath, and assemble it in the deployable app (as needed).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.